# De-Referencing void pointer error when infact already cast

Tags: c, pointers, void

**Situation**

Consider the following source code which aims to print two a's, i.e. output should be "aa":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
char a = 'a';
void* a_pnt = &a;
void* b_pnt = (char*)a_pnt;

printf("%c", *(char*)a_pnt);
printf("%c", *b_pnt);// why is the compiler saying I am dereferencing a void pointer? It was already cast
return 0;
}
```

**Complication**

The printing of the first "a" works but the compiler is giving a compile time error on line 10 (second printing of "a") saying:

> Invalid use of void expression

and a warning on the same line saying:

> Dereferencing 'void *' pointer

Although b_pnt was indeed declared a void pointer, it was cast to a character pointer in its definition on line 7. My only guess as to why its complaining is something to do with the fact that I can only cast when referencing at the same time. My hunch is based off the fact that the first variable works just fine.

**Solution**

The solution is declare and define a character variable called 'b' and cast to character pointer upfront before printing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
char a = 'a';
void* a_pnt = &a;
void* b_pnt = a_pnt;
char b = *((char*)b_pnt);

printf("%c", *(char*)a_pnt);
printf("%c", b);// why is the compiler saying I am dereferencing a pointer?
return 0;
}
```

The question still remains: Why did the initial attempt fail?

I am deliberately starting off with void pointer to illustrate the issue. It could indeed have been avoided entirely ofcourse with the correct pointer type.

Comment: why `void *` but not `char *b_pnt = a_pnt`?

Comment: `(cast)expr` does not affect the type of `expr`. It only affects the type of `(cast)expr`.

Comment: @ensc I am deliberately starting off with void pointer to illustrate the issue. It could indeed have been avoided entirely

Answer (score 1):

Just because you performed a cast when assigning to `b_pnt` doesn't mean that it's type changed.  It's type is still `void *` and dereferencing it is an error.

You can freely assign any non-function pointer type to a `void *` without a warning.  But the compiler doesn't keep track of what kind of pointer was stored there, so it's still a `void *` that needs to be casted before it can be dereferenced.

Comment: It was cast before dereferenced albeit not in the same statement.

Comment: @DeanP It was not cast at any point.  You assigned a casted value to `b_ptr`, but that doesn't change it's type.  Nor does casting it in an unrelated expression.  Casting the type of a variable changes the type *of the value of the variable in that context*, not of the variable itself.